# can't modify frozen Module (FrozenError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eager-loading, dry-validation

locally the app seems to be working fine, I can start the server and the app loads correctly, however, when I deploy to a remote environment I get 500 error, then looking at the logs I see this error `can't modify frozen Module (FrozenError)`

Here's the full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    56: from bin/rails:11:in `<main>'
    55: from bin/rails:11:in `require'
    54: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    53: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    52: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    51: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor.rb:527:in `dispatch'
    50: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    49: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor/command.rb:28:in `run'
    48: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/commands/runner/runner_command.rb:29:in `perform'
    47: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:15:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    46: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:28:in `require_environment!'
    45: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in `require_environment!'
    44: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    43: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    42: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    41: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
    40: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
    39: from /opt/thedeployer/pangea.rewardops.net/releases/20240129183011Z/config/environment.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    38: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:190:in `method_missing'
    37: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:190:in `public_send'
    36: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
    35: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    34: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    33: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    32: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    31: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    30: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    29: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    28: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    27: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    26: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    25: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    24: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    23: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    22: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    21: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `each'
    20: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:356:in `eager_load!'
    19: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `eager_load!'
    18: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `each'
    17: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:477:in `block in eager_load!'
    16: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:477:in `each'
    15: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:478:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
    14: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:246:in `require_dependency'
    13: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:334:in `depend_on'
    12: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:356:in `require_or_load'
    11: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
    10: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading'
     9: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in `exclusive'
     8: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:in `block in loading'
     7: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
     6: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:378:in `block in require_or_load'
     5: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
     4: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
     3: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
     2: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
     1: from /opt/thedeployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
/opt/thedeployer/pangea.rewardops.net/releases/20240129183011Z/app/validation_schemas/override/cash_override/api/create_contract.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': can't modify frozen Module (FrozenError)
```

At the end you can see this line:

```
/opt/thedeployer/pangea.rewardops.net/releases/20240129183011Z/app/validation_schemas/override/cash_override/api/create_contract.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': can't modify frozen Module (FrozenError)
```

It is poitning to this file:

```rb
class Override::CashOverride::Api::CreateContract < AppContract
  # dry-validations file
  # validation code below...
  # ...
end
```

We are in the process of upgrading dry-validations gem from `0.13.x` to `1.x` version, this is one of the files I refactored...

for now the only thing I could do to prevent this error from happening is to change this setting in our environment file `config/environments/qa.rb`:

```rb
# Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
# your application in memory, allowing both thread web servers
# and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
# Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
config.eager_load = false
```

I changed it from `true` to `false` and the app started to work, this is a temporal solution but would like to know why it works when I change this setting?

In prod we have this setting set to `true` and I think we can't just merge this dry-validations upgrade branch with that setting set to `false` that would break things in prod or cause other side effects, but Im not sure about those side effects.

### Update

Adding more details about the file listed in the Traceback `app/validation_schemas/override/cash_override/api/create_contract.rb`, it is a validation contract defined as `class Override::CashOverride::Api::CreateContract` that inherits from `AppContract` located at `app/validation_schemas/app_contract.rb` which is defined as follows:

```rb
class AppContract < Dry::Validation::Contract
  # dry-validations options and configs defined here
  # a bunch of methods used in contracts
  # ...
end
```

Comment: ...in which file is `AppContract` defined?

Comment: Which is the frozen module?

Comment: @smathy added more details at the end about `AppContract`

Comment: @XavierNoria Well the error points to line 1 of `app/validation_schemas/override/cash_override/api/create_contract.rb` which inherits from `AppContract` there's no frozen module from what I can see so far

Comment: Ok nothing weird there. Couldn't be any other AppContract in your app?

Comment: set   `config.eager_load = true` in your development.rb and see if you have the same issue

Comment: @smathy I don't think so if that was the case the app would conflict while trying to start the server locally but it runs locally

Comment: @dbugger I get a different error` `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/svelandiag/Desktop/temas-laborales/zaga/rewardops.nosync/pangea/config/keys/RewardOps-API-CertificationService-GW-UAT.p12 (Errno::ENOENT)`  but I think that it is normal that switching it in development would break other things, wouldn't it

Comment: @svenlandiag but in line 1 several objects are referenced, the frozen module could be `Override`, or `Override::CashOverride`, or `Override::CashOverride::Api`. You could in previous lines list them all and ask `frozen?` on them. It's strange that the error message does not include the name of the module (but I don't know if Ruby 2.6 printed it).

Comment: @svelandiag -- no switching it should not break other things -- it means your code can't build correctly, possibly for multiple reasons